# Insert to beginning of copied vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a `std:;vector<double>` that's the output from a simulation code. The size can be anywhere from O(10^1) to O(10^4). I need to create a new vector that's a copy of this vector with an additional element at the beginning, so I can either write:

```
// old_vec is some std::vector<double> from a simulation code
auto new_vec = old_vec;
double val = 1.0;
new_vec.insert(new_vec.begin(), val);
```

or

```
std::vector<double> new_vec{val};
new_vec.insert(new_vec.end(), old_vec.begin(), old_vec.end());
```

I believe the first approach will cause a reallocation due to the insertion at the beginning of a vector, whereas the second one will just append everything to the end, so the latter seems better? Is there any guarantee that the compiler may optimize the first code into the second code?

Comment: You could use a [std::deque](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) instead of a `std::vector`, where insertions at the beginning and end are fast.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's faster asymptotically, but in practice, isn't `std::vector` alot of the time due to caching issues?

Comment: In both cases, whether or not there will be a reallocation depends on the platform and the content of the vectors. Try to construct a vector, reserve the final size, push the new value, then insert `old_vec` to be sure that no element is moved and no reallocation occurs.

Comment: most likely the compiler can't see these are the same, but the code generation might end up being similar anyway. You should try to reuse old_vec if you can, instead of copying the vector.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't trust directly using the "=" operator to copy the vector, but more of a combination between your two methods. List-initialization may be safer first, then use insert() to add the first element:

```
vector <double> new_vec = {old_vec.begin(), old_vec.end()}; 
new_vec.insert(new_vec.begin(), val);
```

Your suspicions of problems may vary across different compilers, so you may or may not get an error. However, if you would like a foolproof way, that would be outright inserting and copying:

```
vector <double> new_vec; new_vec.push_back(val);
for (double i : old_vec) { new_vec.push_back(i); }
```